# Area chart displays bigger values lower than smaller values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I want to display an area chart with Actual and Cumulative values. While I would expect that the Actual values would be displayed lower than Cumulative the opposite happens and also displays the chart in a very strange way.

```
Tar<-structure(list(Week = structure(c(1L, 1L, 15L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 
8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 18L, 18L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 14L, 5L, 5L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 19L, 19L, 5L, 5L, 17L, 17L, 20L, 
20L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 18L, 18L, 16L, 16L, 7L, 7L, 20L, 
20L, 17L, 17L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 5L, 5L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 
6L, 6L, 14L, 14L, 20L, 20L, 15L, 15L, 8L, 8L, 18L, 18L, 14L, 
14L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 1L, 1L, 16L, 16L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 
20L, 20L, 15L, 15L, 3L, 3L, 19L, 19L, 14L, 14L, 17L, 17L, 10L, 
10L, 20L, 20L, 9L, 9L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 14L, 14L, 5L, 5L, 
18L, 18L, 14L, 14L, 9L, 9L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 16L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 7L, 7L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 10L, 
18L, 18L, 10L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 8L, 17L, 17L, 15L, 
15L, 20L, 20L, 15L, 15L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 16L, 16L, 
7L, 7L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 17L, 17L, 14L, 14L, 20L, 
20L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 5L, 5L, 19L, 19L, 18L, 18L, 
14L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 14L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 3L, 3L, 
20L, 20L, 5L, 5L, 20L, 20L, 17L, 17L, 19L, 19L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 14L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 20L, 20L, 19L, 19L, 17L, 17L, 3L, 3L, 
14L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 20L, 20L, 18L, 
18L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 7L, 7L, 15L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 17L, 17L, 
8L, 8L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 3L, 3L, 19L, 19L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 
17L, 2L, 2L, 20L, 20L, 10L, 10L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 14L, 8L, 8L, 
18L, 18L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 17L, 17L, 3L, 3L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 18L, 18L, 
16L, 16L, 14L, 14L, 4L, 4L, 18L, 18L, 13L, 13L, 6L, 6L, 14L, 
14L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 4L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 14L, 14L, 5L, 5L, 18L, 18L, 8L, 8L, 19L, 
19L, 17L, 17L, 14L, 14L, 17L, 17L, 20L, 20L, 17L, 17L, 15L, 15L, 
18L, 18L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 15L, 15L, 8L, 8L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 
16L, 14L, 14L, 5L, 5L, 19L, 19L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 17L, 17L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 13L, 13L, 18L, 18L, 2L, 2L, 17L, 17L, 14L, 
14L, 20L, 20L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 18L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 20L, 20L, 11L, 11L, 20L, 20L, 16L, 16L, 8L, 8L, 18L, 18L, 
7L, 7L, 14L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 8L, 8L, 
18L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 14L, 4L, 4L, 14L, 14L, 18L, 18L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 20L, 20L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
15L, 15L, 7L, 7L, 17L, 17L, 20L, 20L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 16L, 16L, 
13L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 20L, 20L, 9L, 9L, 4L, 
4L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 5L, 5L, 18L, 18L, 4L, 4L, 16L, 
16L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 20L, 
20L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 14L, 14L, 18L, 18L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 
20L, 20L, 4L, 4L, 13L, 13L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 14L, 14L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 17L, 17L, 
9L, 9L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 16L, 16L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 
13L, 13L, 17L, 17L, 8L, 8L, 17L, 17L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 15L, 15L, 
1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 20L, 20L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 20L, 
20L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 8L, 18L, 18L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 6L, 6L, 
13L, 13L, 5L, 5L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 6L, 6L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 8L, 
15L, 15L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 20L, 
20L, 18L, 18L, 6L, 6L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 8L, 
7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
17L, 17L, 5L, 5L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 15L, 15L, 
7L, 7L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 18L, 18L, 
16L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 20L, 20L, 6L, 6L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 
2L, 8L, 8L, 20L, 20L, 16L, 16L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 3L, 15L, 
15L, 16L, 16L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 5L, 5L, 17L, 17L, 
4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 16L, 16L, 6L, 6L, 20L, 20L, 17L, 17L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 20L, 20L, 7L, 7L, 16L, 16L, 
2L, 2L, 15L, 15L, 20L, 20L, 15L, 15L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 16L, 16L, 
6L, 6L, 19L, 19L, 3L, 3L, 18L, 18L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 18L, 18L, 
20L, 20L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"), class = "factor"), 
    Type = c("Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target", "Cumilative target", 
    "Actual target", "Cumilative target", "Actual target"), Count = c(5, 
    7, 323, 29, 448, 52, 148, 25, 28, 19, 398, 47, 348, 33, 298, 
    37, 73, 27, 298, 37, 323, 29, 148, 25, 198, 8, 423, 10, 73, 
    27, 373, 31, 448, 52, 398, 47, 398, 47, 13, 12, 28, 19, 148, 
    25, 448, 52, 448, 52, 123, 18, 73, 27, 13, 12, 398, 47, 348, 
    33, 123, 18, 448, 52, 373, 31, 448, 52, 448, 52, 73, 27, 
    323, 29, 348, 33, 98, 29, 298, 37, 448, 52, 323, 29, 148, 
    25, 398, 47, 298, 37, 348, 33, 398, 47, 73, 27, 73, 27, 448, 
    52, 448, 52, 448, 52, 5, 7, 348, 33, 123, 18, 173, 8, 323, 
    29, 398, 47, 448, 52, 323, 29, 28, 19, 423, 10, 298, 37, 
    373, 31, 198, 8, 448, 52, 173, 8, 398, 47, 398, 47, 298, 
    37, 73, 27, 398, 47, 298, 37, 173, 8, 373, 31, 348, 33, 173, 
    8, 198, 8, 298, 37, 323, 29, 123, 18, 448, 52, 448, 52, 198, 
    8, 398, 47, 198, 8, 448, 52, 223, 4, 148, 25, 373, 31, 323, 
    29, 448, 52, 323, 29, 223, 4, 148, 25, 73, 27, 348, 33, 123, 
    18, 298, 37, 323, 29, 298, 37, 373, 31, 298, 37, 448, 52, 
    298, 37, 323, 29, 298, 37, 73, 27, 423, 10, 398, 47, 298, 
    37, 28, 19, 298, 37, 148, 25, 298, 37, 323, 29, 28, 19, 448, 
    52, 73, 27, 448, 52, 373, 31, 423, 10, 148, 25, 148, 25, 
    173, 8, 298, 37, 28, 19, 448, 52, 423, 10, 373, 31, 28, 19, 
    298, 37, 5, 7, 348, 33, 398, 47, 398, 47, 448, 52, 398, 47, 
    348, 33, 348, 33, 123, 18, 323, 29, 448, 52, 373, 31, 148, 
    25, 348, 33, 323, 29, 28, 19, 423, 10, 323, 29, 373, 31, 
    13, 12, 448, 52, 198, 8, 348, 33, 298, 37, 148, 25, 398, 
    47, 98, 29, 198, 8, 373, 31, 28, 19, 373, 31, 398, 47, 398, 
    47, 298, 37, 323, 29, 298, 37, 298, 37, 398, 47, 348, 33, 
    298, 37, 48, 19, 398, 47, 273, 12, 98, 29, 298, 37, 323, 
    29, 298, 37, 28, 19, 348, 33, 398, 47, 48, 19, 13, 12, 148, 
    25, 28, 19, 298, 37, 73, 27, 398, 47, 148, 25, 423, 10, 373, 
    31, 298, 37, 373, 31, 448, 52, 373, 31, 323, 29, 398, 47, 
    198, 8, 13, 12, 323, 29, 148, 25, 298, 37, 348, 33, 298, 
    37, 73, 27, 423, 10, 73, 27, 48, 19, 373, 31, 98, 29, 98, 
    29, 48, 19, 273, 12, 398, 47, 13, 12, 373, 31, 298, 37, 448, 
    52, 98, 29, 28, 19, 323, 29, 398, 47, 98, 29, 28, 19, 448, 
    52, 223, 4, 448, 52, 348, 33, 148, 25, 398, 47, 123, 18, 
    298, 37, 5, 7, 48, 19, 448, 52, 448, 52, 148, 25, 398, 47, 
    5, 7, 298, 37, 48, 19, 298, 37, 398, 47, 48, 19, 73, 27, 
    98, 29, 448, 52, 13, 12, 148, 25, 398, 47, 398, 47, 323, 
    29, 123, 18, 373, 31, 448, 52, 148, 25, 73, 27, 348, 33, 
    273, 12, 248, 2, 348, 33, 373, 31, 448, 52, 173, 8, 48, 19, 
    298, 37, 323, 29, 448, 52, 73, 27, 398, 47, 48, 19, 348, 
    33, 13, 12, 98, 29, 123, 18, 28, 19, 273, 12, 273, 12, 448, 
    52, 398, 47, 373, 31, 298, 37, 398, 47, 248, 2, 123, 18, 
    448, 52, 48, 19, 273, 12, 98, 29, 73, 27, 98, 29, 448, 52, 
    448, 52, 298, 37, 98, 29, 73, 27, 48, 19, 13, 12, 373, 31, 
    173, 8, 323, 29, 348, 33, 398, 47, 348, 33, 48, 19, 98, 29, 
    273, 12, 373, 31, 148, 25, 373, 31, 123, 18, 73, 27, 323, 
    29, 5, 7, 98, 29, 48, 19, 448, 52, 73, 27, 28, 19, 98, 29, 
    448, 52, 273, 12, 148, 25, 398, 47, 48, 19, 123, 18, 73, 
    27, 98, 29, 348, 33, 398, 47, 448, 52, 448, 52, 448, 52, 
    98, 29, 273, 12, 73, 27, 348, 33, 373, 31, 98, 29, 273, 12, 
    148, 25, 323, 29, 98, 29, 48, 19, 148, 25, 273, 12, 28, 19, 
    98, 29, 448, 52, 398, 47, 98, 29, 273, 12, 298, 37, 223, 
    4, 148, 25, 123, 18, 48, 19, 348, 33, 348, 33, 373, 31, 5, 
    7, 73, 27, 373, 31, 73, 27, 448, 52, 448, 52, 48, 19, 98, 
    29, 323, 29, 123, 18, 398, 47, 373, 31, 373, 31, 28, 19, 
    73, 27, 398, 47, 348, 33, 398, 47, 398, 47, 448, 52, 98, 
    29, 348, 33, 13, 12, 148, 25, 448, 52, 348, 33, 98, 29, 148, 
    25, 28, 19, 323, 29, 348, 33, 423, 10, 348, 33, 398, 47, 
    73, 27, 373, 31, 48, 19, 98, 29, 348, 33, 98, 29, 448, 52, 
    373, 31, 123, 18, 123, 18, 13, 12, 398, 47, 398, 47, 448, 
    52, 123, 18, 348, 33, 13, 12, 323, 29, 448, 52, 323, 29, 
    48, 19, 73, 27, 348, 33, 98, 29, 423, 10, 28, 19, 398, 47, 
    98, 29, 123, 18, 398, 47, 448, 52, 373, 31, 398, 47, 98, 
    29, 173, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -858L), class = "data.frame")
    
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
p <-
    ggplot(Tar, aes(x = Week, y = Count, fill = Type))+
    geom_area(alpha = 0.6 , size = 0.5, colour = "white", stat = "identity", orientation = "x") +
    labs(fill = NULL)+
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")
p <- p+labs(title = "Figure 1: Weekly Cumulative Projected Enrollment vs Weekly Cumulative Actual Enrollment",
            subtitle = "Cum Weekly Projected Enrollment/Cum Weekly Actual Enrollment")


# not printed
ggplotly(p)
```

This is how it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicate entries for each group and week in your data, hence the messy look. Additionally, to not stack current and cumulative, which is quite misleading, you can set `position = "identity"`. And I brought the actual values to the front via the factor transformation but handle this as you like.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
clean_data <- Tar %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  mutate(Type = ordered(Type, levels = unique(Type)[2:1]))

p <- ggplot(clean_data, aes(x = Week, y = Count, fill = Type, group = Type)) +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.6 , size = 0.5, colour = "white", position = "identity", orientation = "x") +
  labs(fill = NULL)+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
p <- p+labs(title = "Figure 1: Weekly Cumulative Projected Enrollment vs Weekly Cumulative Actual Enrollment",
            subtitle = "Cum Weekly Projected Enrollment/Cum Weekly Actual Enrollment")

p
# not printed
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: I have edited putting my whole dataset but I cannot understand why I get an empty plot now

Comment: actually I am not sure what caused this bug but specifically setting `group = Type` solves the issue. see above

Answer (score 1):

[mnist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69178584/8676170) is complete and solves the problem. He mentioned that you have duplicate records on your dataset. You can either remove them or calculate the mean or total (not sure now if the duplicates are supposed to be there).
Here's an alternative that reorders `Type` and also removes extra lines (`labs(fill = NULL)+`) by adding `legend.title = element_blank()` to the `theme` part. You can also remove the `stat = identity` in this specific case:

### Edit:

Because Original Post was updated with the whole dataset, I'm updating my answer.
Now you have to use `group` in order to make it work:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
p <- Tar %>% 
  group_by(Week, Type) %>% 
  summarise(mean_count = mean(Count)) %>% 
  mutate(Type = factor(Type, levels = rev(unique(Type)))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Week, y = mean_count,
             group = Type)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill = Type),
            alpha = 0.6 , 
            size = 0.5, 
            stat = "identity",
            colour = "white", 
            orientation = "x") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank())

p <- p +
  labs(title = "Figure 1: Weekly Cumulative Projected Enrollment vs Weekly Cumulative Actual Enrollment",
       subtitle = "Cum Weekly Projected Enrollment/Cum Weekly Actual Enrollment")
```

[image]

#### Old answer:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

p <- Tar %>%
  group_by(Week, Type) %>% 
  summarise(mean_count = mean(Count)) %>% 
  mutate(Type = factor(Type, levels = rev(unique(Type)))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Week, 
             y = mean_count, 
             fill = Type)) +
  geom_area(alpha = 0.6 , 
            size = 0.5, 
            colour = "white", 
            orientation = "x") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank())

p <- p +
  labs(title = "Figure 1: Weekly Cumulative Projected Enrollment vs Weekly Cumulative Actual Enrollment",
       subtitle = "Cum Weekly Projected Enrollment/Cum Weekly Actual Enrollment")

p
```

[image]

> Please note that you have a typo on your data: you wrote *Cumilative* and not `Cumulative`.

Comment: I have edited putting my whole dataset but I cannot understand why I get an empty plot now

Comment: Hi @firmo23 I've edited my answer. Note that you must use `group` to make it work. Also note that I'm using `mean` but depending on the purpose of the chart, you can use `sum` instead.